# How to execute a function when user click back button or is leaving . and how to delay it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a pop up that i want it to be show when the user click back button or is leaving , and is there is a method to delay the time of leaving or back to a previous page ?

Here is the popup code:

```
<div style="display: block;" id="ouibounce-modal">
    <div id="popup">
        <div id="close">×</div>
        <div id="popup_img" class="hos_modal">
            <a href="www.google.com/click" 
               onclick="DisableExitTraffic();"><img 
               src="http://placehold.it/500/500"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // if you want to use the 'fire' or 'disable' fn,
    // you need to save OuiBounce to an object

    $("#ouibounce-modal").show();
    var _ouibounce = ouibounce(document.getElementById('ouibounce-
         modal'), {
        aggressive: true,
        timer: 0,
        callback: function () { console.log('ouibounce fired!'); }
    });

    $('body').on('click', function () {
        $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
    });

    $('#ouibounce-modal .modal-footer').on('click', function () {
        $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
    });

    $('#ouibounce-modal .modal').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });



    $("#close").click(function () {
        $("#popup").hide();

    });}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to back button or user leaving the page by adding event listener on `popstate` event.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#ouibounce-modal").show();
};
```

For more details check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below to delay the executions

```
$('body').on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
   }, 1000)
});

$('#ouibounce-modal .modal-footer').on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#ouibounce-modal').hide(); 
    }, 1000)
});

$('#ouibounce-modal .modal').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});



$("#close").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#popup").hide();
    }, 1000)
});}
```

Please note that you can change the delay time by passing the value for the timeout (in my example i have used 1000)
For detail information about setTimeout refer to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp